# Exception: Range exceeds grid limits. Max rows: 1001, max columns: 20",\n "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"

Tags: python, google-sheets, discord, gspread

So I'm making a discord bot, which pulls data from Spreadsheet to performs checks.

```py
async def fetch_sheet():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    global list_of_lists
    i = 0
    while True:
        #if creds.access_token_expired:
        client.login()  # refreshes the token
        list_of_lists = client.open('Guild Roster 2').worksheet("ViP1").get_all_values()
        print("ViP Worksheet Access: Stable")
        i += 1
        print ('Sheet Fetch Count: {0}'.format(i))
        await asyncio.sleep(60)
```

When I run this I get an exception saying I've exceeded the Maximum grid limit. Any idea how to fix this? I read somewhere it was because of other worksheet's name, I even changed that, but still the issue persists:

```
2019-04-21T07:16:12.347017+00:00 app[bot.1]: Task exception was never retrieved
2019-04-21T07:16:12.347060+00:00 app[bot.1]: future: <Task finished coro=<fetch_sheet() done, defined at main.py:63> exception=APIError('{\n  "error": {\n    "code": 400,\n    "message": "Range (\'ViP1\'!VIP1) exceeds grid limits. Max rows: 1001, max columns: 20",\n    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"\n  }\n}\n',)>
2019-04-21T07:16:12.347062+00:00 app[bot.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-04-21T07:16:12.347063+00:00 app[bot.1]:   File "main.py", line 70, in fetch_sheet
2019-04-21T07:16:12.347064+00:00 app[bot.1]:     list_of_lists = client.open('Guild Roster 2').worksheet("ViP1").get_all_values()
2019-04-21T07:16:12.347066+00:00 app[bot.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gspread/models.py", line 444, in get_all_values
2019-04-21T07:16:12.347068+00:00 app[bot.1]:     data = self.spreadsheet.values_get(self.title)
2019-04-21T07:16:12.347069+00:00 app[bot.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gspread/models.py", line 110, in values_get
2019-04-21T07:16:12.347070+00:00 app[bot.1]:     r = self.client.request('get', url, params=params)
2019-04-21T07:16:12.347071+00:00 app[bot.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gspread/client.py", line 79, in request
2019-04-21T07:16:12.347073+00:00 app[bot.1]:     raise APIError(response)
2019-04-21T07:16:12.347074+00:00 app[bot.1]: gspread.exceptions.APIError: {
2019-04-21T07:16:12.347075+00:00 app[bot.1]:   "error": {
2019-04-21T07:16:12.347077+00:00 app[bot.1]:     "code": 400,
2019-04-21T07:16:12.347078+00:00 app[bot.1]:     "message": "Range ('ViP1'!VIP1) exceeds grid limits. Max rows: 1001, max columns: 20",
2019-04-21T07:16:12.347079+00:00 app[bot.1]:     "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
2019-04-21T07:16:12.347080+00:00 app[bot.1]:   }
2019-04-21T07:16:12.347082+00:00 app[bot.1]: }
```

I want to pull the data in the sheet and store it in the "list_of_lists" variable to further use that data to perform different commands.

Answer (score 1):

Don't really know why, but adding an underscore somewhere in worksheet name worked for me. Try renaming "ViP1" to "ViP_1"